# Slick Slider with html 5 videos

Tags: javascript, slick.js

I like to implement this slick slider with html5 videos on my WordPress site: https://codepen.io/digistate/pen/MvapbE

When implemented there is an error saying:

```
TypeError: currentSlide.attr(...) is undefined
```

While checking my HTML markup slick-current class is applied to the current slide.

I'm not a JS-guru so I would like to hear some hints why this could happen.

Thank you for your support!

Best wishes
L

Comment: currentSlide = slick.find(".slick-current"); This line only error.Which means you could not call class name of 'slick-current'. Please add it and look into it

Comment: Thank you! I found out that I was using jquery in a wrong way in wordpress.

Now I was able to implement, but the autoplay function is not working when adding an additional <div> container like in this second slide which I need for my design: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/PLvreP